# Optimizing a Route Selection Problem with Multiple Constraints and Objectives

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, or-tools, vehicle-routing, traveling-salesman

I'm developing a solution to optimize a vehicle routing problem where each stop has an associated score (priority), specific geo coordinates, and a required stop duration. The goal is to maximize the total score of stops visited within a day, considering travel time between stops and a fixed start/end time, ensuring each stop is visited no more than once.

In another words - **I need to find a route that will maximize score collected on the route from start location and ending in end location, we can skip nodes that would not fit into the day schedu**

Objectives:

1. Maximize total value of selected stops.
2. Optimize route to minimize travel time.
3. Fit travel within a day's schedule.

What algorithms or mathematical optimization techniques are recommended for this scenario?
What libraries would you recommend for solving this problem? I have some school experience with ILP modeling and Gurobi, now I was trying OR-tools with no success.
How should I model this problem to efficiently find an optimal or near-optimal solution? Should I rather look for some heuristic approach? I was thinking of some kind of greedy shortest-path algorithm with incorporating the scores and travel distances between stops (for example difference between the node's score and the cost of visiting the node.).

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=orienteering

Comment: If you're open to heuristic solutions, [PyVRP](https://pyvrp.org/) supports your problem setting out of the box. (full disclosure: I'm one of its authors)

Comment: @Nelewout this looks really promising, is there any example how to use the mention library for Prize-collecting VRP?

Comment: @Rastislav not yet, but let me write something up for you in the morning!

Comment: @Nelewout that would be super helpful! I skimmed the whole docs already. Really like the project

Comment: @Rastislav I have added an example to the current development documentation for 0.8.0, [here](https://pyvrp.org/examples/quick_tutorial.html#Prize-collecting-VRP). This should also work with version 0.7.0 that has already been released, but the plots will look a little different there. I hope this helps! Feel free to open an issue in our repository if you have any PyVRP-specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nelewout and his work on library [PyVRP](https://pyvrp.org) it super easy to setup and solve this Vehicle Routing Problem with prize collection (scores) and even with time windows, using heuristics.

```
DURATION_MATRIX = [...]
PRIZES = [...]
PRIZES[0] = 0  # starting point has no prize
COORDS = [...]
START_INDEX = 0

m = Model()

depots = [ # We are going to have only one depot
    m.add_depot(
        x=COORDS[START_INDEX][0],
        y=COORDS[START_INDEX][1],
        tw_early=TIME_WINDOWS[START_INDEX][0],
        tw_late=TIME_WINDOWS[START_INDEX][1],
    )
]

# We are going to have only one vehicle type 
m.add_vehicle_type(1, depot=depots[START_INDEX], max_duration=10)

clients = [
    m.add_client(
        x=COORDS[idx][0],
        y=COORDS[idx][1],
        tw_early=TIME_WINDOWS[idx][0],
        tw_late=TIME_WINDOWS[idx][1],
        prize=PRIZES[idx],
        required=False,
    )
    for idx in range(1, len(COORDS)) # the first one is the depot
]

locations = depots + clients
for frm_idx, frm in enumerate(locations):
    for to_idx, to in enumerate(locations):
        distance = abs(frm.x - to.x) + abs(frm.y - to.y)  # Manhattan
        duration = DURATION_MATRIX[frm_idx][to_idx]
        m.add_edge(frm, to, distance=distance, duration=duration)

res = m.solve(stop=MaxRuntime(5))  # in second
print(res)
```

This is just amazingly easy to setup and use. Thank you for your time and help.